# Accessing model through Varien_Event_Observer

Tags: magento

I have a custom observer in Magento 1.6.2.0 that is called when a CMS page is saved or deleted (events cms_page_delete_before/cms_page_save_before). I have verified (using Mage::log()) that the observer is working, however when I try the following:

```
public function getCmsUrl(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $url = $observer->getEvent()->getPage()->getIdentifier();
    return $url;
}
```

I get nothing returned (rather than "about-us" or "enable-cookies" or whatever URL path the CMS page has). The following code, however, works perfectly fine:

```
public function getProductUrl(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $baseUrl = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getBaseUrl();
    return $baseUrl;
}
```

Can someone let me know what the correct way of accessing a CMS page is when passed via an observer?

Thanks in advance for any help/tips/pointers :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The events `cms_page_delete_before` and `cms_page_save_before` are fired in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`. This it how it looks like in the `beforeSave` function:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before', $this->_getEventData());
```

As you can see, it uses a variable `_eventPrefix` to construct the event key. In the CMS page model, this is set to `cms_page`.

Also notice the part `$this->_getEventData()`. This is how the model, in this case the CMS page, is passed to the observer:

```
protected function _getEventData()
{
    return array(
        'data_object'       => $this,
        $this->_eventObject => $this,
    );
}
```

As you can see, the object has two names, `data_object` and a name defined in a variable, `_eventObject`. In the product model, the name is set to `product`, but in the CMS page model, the variable is missing. Apparently the Magento team forgot to put this in, and as a result, the default name from the core model is used:

```
protected $_eventObject = 'object';
```

That means you can get the CMS page in your observer by using `getObject`:

```
public function myObserver(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $page = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have since learned to employ your technique on other events. I have also found get_class_methods() has helped me work out what's happening too.